# What is the correct aspect ratio to publish video for broadcast television

Tags: broadcasting, aspect, television

I recently had an opportunity to publish video for broadcast television. I need to know what the correct aspect ratio is to publish video to the broadcaster. U.S. television broadcast. I have not received additional information of what the specifications are for the videos just yet. I'm just trying to be one step ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! What country? What broadcaster, if you can share that? What is the material: a program that the broadcaster commissioned, paid long form programming, or a short form interstitial like a commercial or PSA? Did they send you a spec sheet? Did you request a spec sheet if they haven't sent you one already?

Comment: Ask for the specs from your broadcaster. When HD was still a thing, the requirements were quite strict for HD, like at least 50 Mbit/s, usually 4:2:2, usually 29.97 fps interlaced or 59.94 fps progressive. Nowadays, when "HD" is being broadcast at as low as 5 Mbit/s, who cares?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information as commented by @MichaelLiebman
But default would be:
30FPS, 16:9 (1920x1080, 1280x720) either Progressive or interlaced.
Mostly you'll need 4:2:2

Comment: 1080p isn't commonly accepted, at least for paid programming or commercials in the US, and 720p is usually only accepted by ABC and Fox affiliates. But 1080i29.97 with a 4:2:2 profile is a good guess.

Comment: Yeah, as Michael already pointed out, I'd certainly expect 29.97 rather than 30 fps.  The old color pulse timing is still hanging out with us, just like the power oscillation.